# Why Lord Narasimha is worshipped during pradosha timings

Tags: belief, practice

During Pradosha timings 4:30 to 6 PM on Trayodasi thithi,  in case of vaishnavites why Lord Narasimha is worshipped and what is the significance of this?

Comment: What Narayan Mani explained was answer for one part. The significance is whoever prays Lord Narasimha with pure devotion at this time 4/30 to 6 pm on pradosham or atleast from 5/30 to 6 they will win their enemies; they will be blessed with all sorts from the Lord. Citing the instance after Lord Narasimha killed Hriranya his blood thirst was not over. Prahlada [Hriyana's son] with pure devotion prayed the Lord at this juncture to cool down. Immediately Lord came to his ordinary stage and blessed Prahlada and also gave a boon that he will not destroy his vamsas. This was mentioned in kodayin pa

Comment: As nobody gave the exact answer and it was solved by me ccan I take the bounty back?

Comment: No you can't [refer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for details

Comment: @AnkitSharma What I cannot refer?  The answer was not provided exactly by anybody.  Only votes are getting decreased--it is a partial view. If anybody is incapable to answer they have to accept.

Comment: "can I take the bounty back", no you can't get the bounty back, refer to the mentioned link for details. I hope it's clear now

Comment: Vast rules than Income tax

Comment: I can't help with that, StackExchange network work like that

Comment: not blaming you.

Answer (score 3):

The legend of Narasimham and Prahalad goes like this,

> Hiranyakashipu asks for a tricky boon. That he would *not die either on earth or in space; nor in fire nor in water; **neither during day nor at night**; neither inside nor outside (of a home); nor by a human, animal or God; neither by inanimate nor by animate being*.
>
> Brahma grants the boon. With virtually no fear of death he unleashes terror... (SB 7.3.35-38)
>
> Prahlada, Hiranyakashipu's son who is a stauch Vishnu devotee declares the omnipresence of Lord Vishnu and refuses to worship his own father as the Lord of the world.
>
> Once Hiranyakashipu points to a pillar and asks if Vishnu is present in it. Prahlada nods in affirmative. Angered at it, he draws his sword and cuts the pillar; Narasimha appears out of the broken pillar.
>
> Narasimha (being a man-lion god form) kills Hiranyakashipu. He comes out to kill at the ***pradosha or twilight*** (neither day nor night);on the doorsteps of his palace (neither inside nor outside); uses his nails to kill (neither animate nor inanimate); puts him on his lap before killing (neither earth nor in space). Thus making power of the boon ineffective. (SB 7.8)

Thus, pradosha is the time when Narasimha completed his principal objective of his avatara and thus rescused Prahalada. Vishnu devotees observe silence or *mauna* during the period. No *mantras* are recited during the period either.

Comment: Citing of purana not mentioned-----This story is known to everybody. At the pradosha time mantra raja padam stortram is recited,Runa vimochana narasimha stotram is recited etc. This is a regular one at Kattu azhagiya singar temple srirangam.

Comment: >This story is known to everybody. 
That's exactly why I didn't bother to cite.

Comment: You have to be specific quoting the  chapter if it is mentioned in Narasimha purana or sri bhagavadham etc.

Answer (score 3):

Though the answer above is correct but as it is required here to quote from specific Purana, so I am quoting from Narsingh Purana which is considered to be Uppurana.

The story is mentioned in Narsingh Purana Chapter 44.

> तावद्धता युद्ध्यमाना दैत्याः कोटिसहस्त्रशः।
>
> नरसिंहेन यावच्च नभोभागं गतो रविःः।।२७

Until sun is not set (gone to west), lord Narsingh was fighting with lacs and crores of demons.

> शस्त्रास्त्रवर्षचतुरं हिरण्यकशिपुं जवात्।
>
> प्रगृहृं तु बलाद्राजन् नरसिंहो महाबलः।।२८

But when sun is about to set, the almighty Narsingh has forcefully grabbed the knower of all weapons Hiranyakashipu.

> संंध्याकाले गृहद्वारि स्थित्वारी स्थाप्य तं रिपुम्।
>
> वज्रतुल्यमहोरस्कं हिरण्यकशिपुं रुषा।
>
> नखैः किसलयमिव दारयत्याह सोसुरः।।२९

Then at the time of evening at the door lord Narsingh plunked down Hiranyakashipu on his thigh and started tearing him by his nails.

**Note**- I have sanskrit and hindi version of this book. The english translation is written by me. So, if anyone got any issue please suggest.

Comment: @TN Mani Thanks for your efforts. This is a polished version of the other answer but quoted from purana. Some more deep effort required to fulfil the answer.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Can you please mention what else you required? Thanks.

Comment: @TN Mani---Your answer is an advanced one of the other reply. My question is has it been mentioned in puranans what is the significance when we pray Lord Narasimha during the pradosham timing? You have cited from Purana the war between Lord and the demons. That is why I need an effort much deep.

Answer (score 3):

Found this in indiadevine site (http://www.indiadivine.org/content/topic/980214-krishnanarayanalord-siva/?do=findComment&comment=5784716)  Wish to share the same.

> Narasimha is Narayana and Sadashiva
>
> Problem is that many people hasn't understood "Narasimhadeva".
>   Narasimhadeva has no beginning  or end. He is Original "Narayana". He
>   is source of all avatars. He is source of heat of the sun and keeping
>   cool laxmi maa (parashakti) on his chest/lap. He has nine planets in
>   his divine face. All panch buthas are at his feet. All gods do their
>   job by his fear or bakthi towards him.
>
> He is keeping yoga-maya as his illusinory energy. He is the aadi
>   omkara jwala. He is Narayana. All mantras, tantras, sastras, weapons
>   come from him and surrender within him. He generated Maha-Sudarshana
>   Chakra from it all gods got their weapons. He controls the time thru
>   his kala-chakra. (behind every sudarsha chakra shrine you can see
>   narasimha sitting). He ends everything thru his third eye at end of
>   kalpa. At that time he himself is Sada-shiva or mahaa-kalaa. For
>   Vaishnavas he gives his divine darshan thru his divine Vasudeva form.
>   For Shaivas [rudras followers (not pseudo-shaivas)] or Siddas or
>   Rishis he gives watever powers they ask by giving darshan in form of
>   divine aadi-jyoti.   They worship him in form of Linga. He is the one
>   who resides within each linga. Rudra represents our body. Linga
>   represents our aatma.   Inside our aatma "narasimha" resides as
>   aatma-jyothi. In all shiva temples you can see rudra outside as
>   urchava, since hes outside the linga. Inside linga it is "Narasimha -
>   the param jyoti" residing. Whenever siddhas enjoy bliss of this jyoti
>   they dance with joy. Since this dance is divine, this dance is taken
>   as form of worship. Rudra being a chief of all siddhas dances in this
>   way so hes called nataraja. Dance is called bharatanatyam. During
>   shivarathri siddhas (including rudra) realises this parama-jyoti. So
>   special Worship is done at siddha pittas, rudra temples and
>   shiva-lingas as parama-jyoti is residing inside the linga (aatma).
>   The above truth is beautifully illustrated by Madhvacharya.
>   Shivarathri are celebreated by Madhvas also. Pradhosam is celebreated
>   in all great Narasimha temples.
>
> At Pradosham time Narashima give's darshan to everyone. At this time
>   he accepts all prayers of devas, rudra, brahma and gurus. So at
>   pradosham time, in shiva temples only nandi is collecting prayer from
>   us as rudra is busy in worshippine narasimha (eventhough shaivatees
>   will say something reverse).   When Rudra tells in his Gita that
>   Sada-Siva is supreme, he is actually referring Narayana(Narasimha).
>   Since Gita told by Rudra (in padma purana) may create confusion, all
>   acharyas took "Bhagavath Gita" told by Lord Krishna (narasimha
>   himself) as authorotative. Read Narasimha Upanishads, Narashima
>   Sahasranama and Narasihma Purana. There everything explained clearly. 
>   Also Read Sri Vedantha Desikars commentary about Narasimhadeva. he
>   clearly explains above. Also Nammalwar told It is Narasimha residing
>   everywhere. Even in Vishnu Sahasranama it is Narasimha pointed out at
>   many times. It is narasimha praised as Sadashiva in "shiva
>   sahasranama". All Gods have praised stotras in praise of Narashima.
>   Even Narasimhas own avatars have worshiped  and praised Narasimhadeva.
>   So whenever someone tells Rama/krishna worshipped linga then it should
>   be understood that they worshiiped Narasimha thru linga. Worshpiing
>   Narasimha in form of linga is very ancient method as its easy to make
>   a linga than sculpting his divine form. Only after people gained
>   mastery over crafts they started sculpting narasimha and his divine
>   forms. Both Madhvacharya and Vedantha desikar had told that when
>   narasimha killed hiranyakashipu, blood of hiranya was consumed by
>   narasimadeva to wash off his sins(as requested by prahlada alwar), [in
>   narasimha temples panaga representing blood is given as prasada to
>   narasimhadeva]. hiranyas hide(skin) was worn by virabadra, hiranyas
>   head is accepted by Kaalidevi, hiranyas soul is given to saraba(death
>   ie., rudra) who made sure that this aatma will born again according to
>   its karma. Even death(saraba) is controlled by Narasimha only.
>   Narsimhadeva's anger was calmed down by Prahladalwar's prayers (as God
>   stoops down to devotees pure prayers, he cant be controlled thru
>   ahankara). But shivapurana being tamasic it illustrates everything as
>   reverse just as kaali devotees wrongly tell as though kaali defeated
>   rudra (but actually rudra defeated kaali). It is Narasimhadeva
>   standing in his divine form as "Venkateswara" in Tirumala as to his
>   devotees as he always gives darshan thru his divine Vasudeva form.
>   Since Vaishnavas are soft-hearted Narasimha always gives darshan in
>   form of divine Vasudeva form. Thats why worshiping Narasimha in form
>   of Vasudeva, Rama, krishna is much more prevalent than form of
>   Narasimha himself. Om Namo Narayanaya.

Comment: www.indiadivine.org----type this and explore

Comment: Link is not working. Can you cite some authentic sources to support your claims?

Comment: @Parthasarathy Raghavan - Vishnu worship in Linga form is provided in Pancharatra agamas. In fact Madhvas, followers of Madhvacharya worship Ananteshwara, Lord Vishnu who is the antaryami of Siva linga. Ananteshwara is a famous pilgrimage centre for Madhvas.

Comment: @Krishna - I belong to srirangam where the temple comes under pancharata agama only. Even vadakali sect is not allowed in ranganatha temple. There is no question of Vishnu worship in lingam form. You substantiate your evidence with exact sentences chapter number etc so that I will correlate your answer by checking in the temple.

Comment: #destroyer--link is not working means due to technical faults. Go thru the citations referred. Neither you provide the right answer nor you accept the answer given.

Comment: @Parthasarathy Raghavan - You are right, SriRangam temple is based on Panchartara agama. I am just saying Sanat Kumara Samhita (Panchartara agama) seems to refers to  worship of each of Brahma, Vishnu and Shankara separately in Linga form (A book called Pancharatra agama by V.Varadachari? published by TTD). Now, what exactly is meaning of Linga here is matter of debate. Because "Linga" means mark, symbol etc even as per Sanskrit Grammar. i can provide the exact verse, if you need.

Comment: @Parthasarathy Raghavan - Infact, the answer you have provided is good as it seems to provide new insights into Narasimha avatara...As per Vaishnava philosophy Siva/Rudra/SadaShiva are all considered to be emanations of Narasimha or Sankarshana aspect. That is why Narasimha is praised and extolled wonderfully in Narsimha poorva and uttara tapani upanishads for which Adi Shankara and Vidyaranya have written commentaries. Vedanta Desika mentions in his kAmAshikAshtakam that Narasimha is the essence of the uttara bhagam of the VedA, ie, the Upanishad and is revealed by the tApanIya.

Comment: @Parthasarathy Raghavan - I am given to an understanding that, vedA bhashyakaras make a reference to narasimha tApanIya while commenting on the famous mantram of Satarudriyam "namO hiranyabahavE hiranyapatayE umApatayE ambikApatayE namO namaha". BTW, narasimha tApanIya Upanishad is indeed accepted by all vaidikas and has been quoted by Adi Shankara, Sureshvara, Vedanta Desika, Vidyaranya, Madhva and Ranga Ramanuja Muni cutting across Advaitins, Visistadvaitins and Dvaitins.

Comment: @Parthasarathy Raghavan -  Sanatkumara Samhita -Brahma khanda? ( Pancharatra agama) - verse 6.50b, 51a is as follows - Lingam tu vivida m proktham Brahma Shankara may vacham! Vaishnavam nidaivam cha chaturtha parikeerthitham!! Meaning as provided in A book called " Pancharatra agama by Dr V.Varadachary "- there were Lingas for Brahma, Shankara, Vishnu and all other gods. The three deities are treated as represented by these Lingas.

Comment: @Krishna - Thanks for your exploration.In srirangam temple they are not accepting vadakalai sect even Swami Nikamanda desika . They will not consider this Lord shiva at all. Only we do have Lord Narasimha as  creator, preserver and destroyer.Kindly go thru my other question mantra raja pada stotram  for which Tezz has explained in a neat fashion. Vaishanavites will argue for their sect as well as saivaites. There is no end to this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43855/discussion-between-krishna-and-parthasarathy-raghavan).

Comment: In the chat I left the message.

Comment: @Krishna--Lord Ranganatha's urchavamgal are done. Imeant even pn swamy desikan's thiru nakshatram they are not allowing for going round the four uthra streets.